# Getting error "You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type." when using Webpack to compile ES6 assets

Tags: javascript, webpack, babeljs

I using Webpack with Babel to compile ES6 assets in my Nodejs application, but I am getting the following error message:

```
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type.
|
|       const addMrnObj = {
|         ...jsonObj,
|         optionalMrn: optionalMrn
|       };
 @ ./config/eventSource/eventSourceCall.js 5:18-40
 @ ./src/app.js
 @ multi ./src/app.js
```

I am using Webpack of version 2.2.1 and babel-preset-es2015 of version 6.22.0

Below is my babel.rc configuration

```
{
  "presets": [
    "es2015"
  ],
  "plugins": [
    "transform-flow-strip-types",
    "transform-object-rest-spread",
    "transform-class-properties",
    "syntax-class-properties"
  ]
}
```

And this is my Webpack configuration

```
var webpack = require('webpack');
var path = require('path');
var fs = require('fs');
var BabiliPlugin = require('babili-webpack-plugin');
var CopyWebpackPlugin = require('copy-webpack-plugin');

var BUILD_DIR = path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist');
var APP_DIR = path.resolve(__dirname, 'src');

var config = {
  entry: [
    APP_DIR + '/app.js',
  ],
  target: 'node',
  output: {
    path: BUILD_DIR,
    filename: 'backend.js'
  },
  plugins: [
    new BabiliPlugin(),
    new CopyWebpackPlugin([{
      from: './config',
      to: 'config'
    }])
  ],
  module: {
    loaders: [
      {
        test: /\.js?/,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        include: [ APP_DIR ],
        loader: 'babel-loader'
      }
    ]
  }
};

module.exports = config;
```

Can someone point out what additional changes I need to make to resolve this error.

Comment: Can you attach content of file `src/app.js` ?

Comment: As this app.js file is quiet big i will not be able to attach the contents but in my question I have mentioned that exact snippet that is causing the issue i.e. spread operator.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding "@babel/preset-env" in babel.rc file under presets(also install presets).
and also your syntax is wrong this should be

```
{
  "presets": ["@babel/preset-es2015"]
}
```

and file name should be .babelrc not babel.rc